# How do you restart an Area51 proposal?

Tags: support, area-51

On the [recently closed CAD proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80927/computer-aided-design-cad) it says:

> Keep the proposal alive by restarting it. See [Closing a Proposal After 1+ Year in Definition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/closing-a-proposal-after-1-year-in-definition-or-commitment).

On the linked topic it says:

> **A New Beginning for Your Proposal**
>
> Closing a slow-growing proposal doesn't have to be the end of the process. If you still believe your site will work, feel free to restart the proposal and prove it.

In April of 2014, [somebody asked about this process on the meta there](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13984/how-does-one-restart-a-proposal), but the answer remains secret.

How do you restart the proposal? Is there a restart button somewhere? Is there a "keep current followers, questions, and topics, and extend proposal another year" procedure? Do you just start from scratch, maybe post a signpost topic on the old one, and see if the followers read it and repost their example questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there's no button. You just have to re-propose it.

Just select a category, and propose the site again just as you would with a new site.

You'll have to start from scratch, but this makes sense. You can always reuse questions, but part of the reason for resetting followers is to make sure that there is still a community that supports the proposal, and that they are still around. Closed proposals will stay alive for 30 days, which should help you restart finely.

Comment: Is it bad manners to copy other people's example questions from the previous proposal?

Comment: I think initially yes, but you should make sure to inform people (they won't get a notification that the proposal is closed). After a while, just rephrase them and you'd probably be fine.